# putting 3 switches in one

Tags: c#, switch-statement, console-application

I have for some time been working on a console calendar that counts on its own to a certain date with the correct day of week, date etc, which then allows you to insert data on that day. All that is done, but now I'm adding a function where you can put the dates from start date to end date into a text file. The output will be something like:

```
05.06.2016 Tuesday
06.06.2016 Wednesday
07.06.2016 Thursday
01.06.2016 Friday
02.06.2016 Saturday
03.01.2016 Sunday
04.01.2016 Monday
05.01.2016 Tuesday
06.01.2016 Wednesday
07.01.2016 Thursday
01.01.2016 Friday
02.01.2016 Saturday
```

This sent me off to this MainInputSection class of my program, and I had to add parameter so that I could alter the messages from just "Input YEAR" etc to "Input start of YEAR for file" etc.

There are now three switches right next to each other that does almost the same thing, and this section of my program therefore felt a bit simple, repetetive, and hard-coded.

What I'd like is a loop or something that shortens this stuff and makes it less nooby the way it is now in order to get the right `Console.WriteLine();` matched with the correct `Console.ReadLine();` to fill in the `int[] arrayAnswers = { answerYear, answerMonth, answerDay };` correcly, but more professionally. I'm thinking something like a for each loop or something, but I only halfway see a solution like that and I need help.

```
public class MainInputSection
{
    public static int[] GetUserInputDate(string mode) 
    {
        int answerYear;
        int answerMonth;
        int answerDay;

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        switch (mode)
        {
            case "calender":                    
                Console.WriteLine("Input YEAR");                    
                break;
            case "fileStart":
                Console.WriteLine("Input start of YEAR for file");
                break;
            case "fileEnd":
                Console.WriteLine("Input end of YEAR for file");
                break;
        }
        Console.ResetColor();
        answerYear = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        switch (mode)
        {
            case "calendar":                    
                Console.WriteLine("Input MONTH");
                break;
            case "fileStart":
                Console.WriteLine("Input start of MONTH for file");
                break;
            case "fileEnd":
                Console.WriteLine("Input end of MONTH for file");
                break;
        }
        Console.ResetColor();            
        answerMonth = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        switch (mode)
        {
            case "calendar":
                Console.WriteLine("Input DAY");
                break;
            case "fileStart":
                Console.WriteLine("Input start of DAY for file");
                break;
            case "fileEnd":
                Console.WriteLine("Input end of DAY for file");
                break;
        }
        Console.ResetColor();
        answerDay = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] arrayAnswers = { answerYear, answerMonth, answerDay };

        return arrayAnswers;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you have to do is, group the common things together inside a method, here all cases should display some text in the console with a color and then call the reset color option, and store the user input to an integer variable. So group them together inside a method and return the integer value from the method. I think the signature of the method should be like the following:

```
 public static int GetInput(string displayMessage)
 {
     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
     Console.WriteLine(displayMessage);
     Console.ResetColor();
     return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 }
```

And you can use the method like the following:

```
public static int[] GetUserInputDate(string mode)
{
    int answerYear = 0;
    int answerMonth = 0;
    int answerDay = 0;
    switch (mode)
    {
        case "calender":
            answerYear = GetInput("Input YEAR");
            answerMonth = GetInput("Input MONTH");
            answerDay = GetInput("Input DAY");
            break;
        case "fileStart":
            answerYear = GetInput("Input start of YEAR for file");
            answerMonth = GetInput("Input start of MONTH for file");
            answerDay = GetInput("Input start of DAY for file");
            break;
        case "fileEnd":
            answerYear = GetInput("Input end of YEAR for file");
            answerMonth = GetInput("Input end of MONTH for file");
            answerDay = GetInput("Input end of DAY for file");
            break;
    }

    int[] arrayAnswers = { answerYear, answerMonth, answerDay };

    return arrayAnswers;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Something like this is exactly what I was hoping for :)